# Issue with docker web server working with self-signed certificates

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

> I am trying to get a web server working with self-signed certificates.
> Based on the example on [this github page](https://github.com/monicahq/docker/tree/main/.examples/nginx-proxy-self-signed-ssl). But I get this error on
> the "https://"
>
> nginx.1     | 2023/05/26 22:28:51 [error] 66#66: *1 cannot load
> certificate "data:": PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX() failed (SSL:
> error:0480006C:PEM routines::no start line:Expecting: TRUSTED
> CERTIFICATE) while SSL handshaking, client: 192.168.0.1, server:
> 0.0.0.0:443
>
> and a 503 error on the "http://"
>
> There are no errors in the logs for the webserver or the app server.
>
> I have properly generated and verified them:
>
> certs/monica.local.crt:  PEM certificate certs/monica.local.csr:  PEM
> certificate request certs/monica.local.pem:  PEM certificate
>
> My nginx.conf:
>
> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xRiyZblElj4EknziL-5KAC08AE5xJA2B/view?usp=share_link
>
> My docker-compose file:
>
> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RxMqq2Uz5wru2l5jarDT7KPLtPSDjz7v/view?usp=share_link
>
> It wouldn't let me post them as code, so I've made links to the file
> on my Google Drive. Which is annoying because I know people don't like
> to open random links.